# How to use dotenv in Codesandbox online editor

Tags: javascript

trying to use the API key which needs to be hidden.

It is a **Pure javascript** code that **uses fetch API for https request** for getting data from the **api**.Using  **online Editor CODESANDBOX**.

For demo purposes.Want to **hide the API Key**

using **dotenv package** [https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv].**how to use dotenv in Codesandbox**

Or there is any other way to hide Api key in Codesanbox using **Pure javascript** code with an API call for the data to display data.

Comment: use https://glitch.com/

Answer (score 0):

Create a `.env` in root of project and `require('dotenv')` in index.js file.

```
import "./styles.css";
require("dotenv").config();

document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = `
<h1>Hello Vanilla!</h1>
<div>
  We use Parcel to bundle this sandbox, you can find more info about Parcel
  <a href="https://parceljs.org" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">here</a>.
</div>
<div>
  ${JSON.stringify(process.env, null, 2)}
</div>
`;

console.log("env", process.env);
```

Have a look at this sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-wave-mz3y1

Comment: @ Murli Prajapati thanks .But it will hide the API Key like build (Production on server) on Codesandbox.

Comment: @Siddhesh There is no real way to hide api key in web frontend applications. It will be visible in API request in Network tab of devtools. Most you can do is remove the key while sharing the project with others so that your key does not get exploited.